# What non parametric should I choose?

Tags: nonparametric

I Have an hypothesis that say : " London have more jobs posts more than other cities " , I have dataframe with column of the cities and the number of jobs posts (c(London,Manchester,Bristol..),c(26,14,11...)), I did the normality and found out that p-value are lower than 5% that mean I should use one of the non-parametric test , but I don't known if it is one sample or two sample and which test (image of lists of the non parametric tests).
Thanks for reading and I appreciate your help.[image: image of lists of the non parametric tests]

Comment: Your brief description of your data seems to show only one value for each city. Are you comparing London with all the other cities? // It is not clear what your diagram of various texts has to do with your question.

Comment: @BruceET
yes I do compare London with all other cities to see if the hypothesis is right (H0 , or H1) there is a lot of job post and each one have some informations and the ones I am studying in this hypothesis is city and the number of posts .

Comment: Then London has a fixed value and you use a one-sample test for the comparison. If job postings outside of London are normal, it could be a one-sample t test.

Comment: what you mean by " job postings outside of London are normal" if you mean if they fit the normal distribution then no , the p value is very small (like 1*10^7) , because there is only three or forth city have good numbers like 8,9,10 and all the others between 1-3 , thank you for your help

Comment: This question might be a learning exercise. But even then the setup is not very compelling. London is much bigger than the other cities. So London will have more jobs even if Londoners have the same number of opportunities per person. You probably should take number of residents in city into account. To add perspective. Population: London 9 million, Bristol 467,000.

Comment: Just saw this after my continued comment. If **all** 0f 50 cities outside London have numbers of job postings below 26, then a sign test rejects $H_0$ with P-value  $(0.5)^{50} \approx 0.$

Comment: [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test) on sign tests.

Comment: @dipetkov
the data I took it by scraping a website have job offers and for every job offer there is number of posts and city as an location of the job , so there is no such data as number of residents in city . I known it's obvious london have more jobs but I'm a beginner in statistics and trying to practice analyzing an hypothesis

Comment: You can scrape just as easily the city population, Wikipedia has this info. The meaning of a hypothesis is just as important as correct computation of the statistic/p-value.

Comment: Or even better check if the ONS (Office of National Statistics) provides population size data. [data from the ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datalist?filter=datasets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment continued: With the information given, it is not possible to answer the
question for your data. So I have shown how to analyze
similar fictitious data.

Suppose you have vector `x` with numbers of job postings outside
London. (Using R.)

```
set.seed(2022)
x = round(rnorm(50, 20, 4))
max(x)
[1] 25
```

In my fictitious data for 50 cities outside London have numbers of postings 25 or less.

```
summary(x);  sd(x)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   8.00   17.00   20.00   19.44   21.75   25.00 
 [1] 3.476804
```

So, a one-sample t t.test of $H_0: \mu \le 26$ against $H_a: \mu > 26$ is
overwhelming rejected with a P-value near $0.$

```
t.test(x, mu = 26, alt="less")$p.val
[1] 3.099603e-18
```

The stripchart (or dotplot) below shows the data.

```
stripchart(c(26,x), pch=20, meth="stack")
 abline(v = 26, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Of course, I have no way to know the actual numbers of job postings
outside London, so the answer for your real data may differ.

*Note:* With the data summary I have given it should be
easy to compute the t test by hand, and I recommend you do so.

Complete output for `t.test`:

```
t.test(x, mu = 26, alt="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -13.342, df = 49, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 26
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 20.26435
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    19.44
```

Output from sign test in Minitab:

```
Sign Test for Median: x

Sign test of median =  26.00 versus < 26.00

     N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
x   50     50      0      0  0.0000   20.00
```

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation , as a beginner in statistics this is really gonna help me to understand better , one more question you said : " If all 0f 50 cities outside London have numbers of job postings below 26, then a sign test rejects H0 with P-value ". yes they all have numbers below 26  , why using sign test and not t test . thank you again for your help.

Comment: You said data not normal, so even with $n$ as large as 50, I'd be reluctant to use t test when there is obvious alternative.

Comment: Sign test is simplest nonparametric test. Wilcoxon test would have been a possibility however there are a couple of difficulties with it here. (1) If there are ties, the one-sample Wilcoxon test may not be able to give an exact P-value. (2) Also, one-sample Wilcoxon test works best as a test for median when the sample is symmetrical. (My fictitious sample is somewhat left skewed as seen in stripchart.) There is no doubt that sign test is applicable. // Added sign test to end of my extended comment. Enjoy your statistics course!